# Need to trigger a workflow when document Set added/updated in sharepoint library

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, document-set

I'm trying to trigger workflow on document library when new document set is created.

Is it possible to triggered a workflow  when Document Set Created/Updated in SharePoint Library?

Please suggest something

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Workflow for you Document Library

Set the workflow settings

When Item is created

when Item update/ Change

It will trigger when item create and update.

Comment: My condition is When Document Set is created in document library. 
Not when document is uploaded

Comment: Yes when you create the item in document Library it also work.

Comment: I'm creating Document Set in Library using SharePoint 2010 workflow which is attached to another library

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Create an Item Created Workflow on the document library.
Then check the content type of created\uploaded item.

if Content Type equals "Document Set"
   Put your logic