# Trigger Workflow on Document Set/ Folder creation

Tags: designer-workflow, folder, document-set

I'm trying to trigger workflow on Document Set/Folder  creation.

Is it possible trigger workflow automatically on Document Set/ Folder creation in library .

I there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone answered this already.

[Need to trigger a workflow when document Set added/updated in sharepoint library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201741/need-to-trigger-a-workflow-when-document-set-added-updated-in-sharepoint-library?rq=1][1])

Does that work for you?

Comment: No Please read the comments from answer